# AVPlayer, how to save the current recording time

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When I press pause and then play, the music playing again how to solve this problem? 
I know that I need to use `seekTime(: CMTime)`, but I don't get

[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cb8i.gif)

It's all code

```
class ViewControllerAudioDetail: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var list: TableViewControllerAudioList!

@IBOutlet weak var playChange: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timeAudio: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playbackSlider: UISlider!


var player = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "БИБЛИОТЕКА"
   }

@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
    if player.rate == 0 {

        let url = URL(string: ViewControllerAudioDetail.urlAudio[0])
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player.rate = 1.0;
        player.play()
        playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        playbackSlider.tintColor = UIColor.green

        let _ = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in
            self?.playbackSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(seconds)

       }

    } else {

        playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        player.pause()

    }        
}


@IBAction func audioPlaybackSlider(_ sender: Any) {


    //перемотка аудиозвука
     let duration : CMTime = player.currentItem!.duration
    let totalDuration : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

    let value = self.playbackSlider.value
    let durationToSeek = Float(totalDuration) * value
    player.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(durationToSeek),player.currentItem!.duration.timescale)) { [](state) in
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, you always create a new player object inside your play method. That is why it always starts from the beginning of the audio.

#### This should solve your problem

```
class ViewControllerAudioDetail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var list: TableViewControllerAudioList!

    @IBOutlet weak var playChange: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeAudio: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playbackSlider: UISlider!


    var player:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "БИБЛИОТЕКА"
        setupAudioPlayer()

    }

    func setupAudioPlayer(){

        let url = URL(string: ViewControllerAudioDetail.urlAudio[0])
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        playbackSlider.tintColor = UIColor.green

        let _ = player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in
            self?.updateSlider(time: time)
        }

    }

    func updateSlider(time:CMTime){

        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
        self.playbackSlider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(duration)

    }

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

        if player?.rate == 0 {

            player?.rate = 1.0;
            player?.play()
            playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        } else {

            playChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            player?.pause()

        }
    }

    @IBAction func audioPlaybackSlider(_ sender: Any) {

        //перемотка аудиозвука
        let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
        let value = self.playbackSlider.value
        let durationToSeek = Float(duration) * value

        self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(durationToSeek),player!.currentItem!.duration.timescale)) { [](state) in

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Comparing non-optional value of type 'AVPlayer' to nil always returns false

Comment: They why you always create a new instance of AVPlayer in your code, player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)

Comment: I added observer for the slider, and your code does not work

Comment: Your question is not very clear my friend, can you explain your problem ?

Comment: I understand your question, but can you post the full code (.swift) ?. Then it's easier to answer. Problem is with your "player" instance.

Comment: Your method has a small bug, when run the player displays an error fatal error: Index out of range